# Ios details of storage files

Tags: iphone, ipad, file, storage, nsfilemanager

I'm looking for a function that allows me to list the contents of files in my iphone, I'll explain, I'm trying to do so he knows the number of images, music files, applications, etc. etc. stored in the device and the various details, name, size, creation date, etc., there is some function that does this?

Thanks

Comment: You can only look at file inside of your app's sandbox. Although you can get to some files outside the sandbox, the app will be rejected if you attempt to read/catalogue them (and most are inaccessible anyway).